# Adding data to an exception

Tags: java, exception

I have a use case where I want to process a list of items. The processing is not atomic and it might succeed for some of the items in the list and fail for some other items. I want to communicate to the users of the API that for some items in the list, the processing failed. I have 3 options:

1. Return a list with items that succeeded
2. Return a list with items that failed
3. Throw an exception saying that some items failed

If I go with the 3rd approach and still want to let the clients know the items for which the processing failed, can I add a List to the exception class and have the clients read this list when they get an exception? Is this advisable? Is there something else that can be done here?

The exception class will look like below:

```
@Getter @Setter
public class SomeProcessingException extends Exception {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private List<SomeItem> failedItems;

  public SomeProcessingException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not SO question, it is based on your requirement

Comment: @Deadpool I understand this is based on my requirement. I just want to know if there is something wrong with doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can extends `Exception` and add the `List` of failed items as you already did.

For the part:

> still want to let the **clients** know the items for which the processing failed

What is a client for you? An end user? Or a programmer using your library? An administrator?

If it is a programmer he can catch your `SomeProcessingException` and get the list of failed items from it.

If it is an end user looking at the logs (an admin for example) you have to rewrite the `toString` method of `SomeProcessingException`.

If it is an end user using a client (browser, android phone, desktop application...) you have to intercept the `SomeProcessingException` and show a popup or similar extracting the failed items from it.

---

Many standard exceptions offer an access to their internal properties that can be used by the used of the class, for example [`URISyntaxException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URISyntaxException.html) has the method [`getIndex()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URISyntaxException.html#getIndex()) to:

> Returns an index into the input string of the position at which the parse error occurred, or -1 if this position is not known.

Similarly [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) has the method [`getErrorCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getErrorCode()) to:

> Retrieves the vendor-specific exception code for this SQLException object.

Comment: Clients for me would be users of my library. So this is feasible for me. The reason I asked this question was I have never seen any code do this kind of handling.

Comment: @MohamedShakeel is possible to retrieve those informations and many standard Exceptions handle it. It is the programmer that choose to use it or not. (Check the updated answer)